# Working with text classification and big sparse matrices in R

Tags: r, classification, text-mining, r-caret, quanteda

I'm working on a text multi-class classification project and I need to build the document / term matrices and train and test in R language.

I already have datasets that don't fit in the limited dimensionality of the base matrix class in R and would need to build big sparse matrices to be able to classify for example, 100k tweets. I am using the **quanteda** package, as it has been for now more useful and reliable than the package **tm**, where creating a DocumentTermMatrix with a dictionary, makes the process incredibly memory hungry with small datasets. Currently, as I said, I use **quanteda** to build the equivalent Document Term Matrix container that later on I transform into a data.frame to perform the training.

I want to know if there is a way to build such big matrices. I have been reading about the **bigmemory** package that allows this kind of container but I am not sure it will work with **caret** for the later classification. Overall I want to understand the problem and build a workaround to be able to work with bigger datasets, as the RAM is not a (big) problem (32GB) but I'm trying to find a way to do it and I feel completely lost about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At what moment did you reach ram constraints?

`quanteda` is good package to work with NLP on medium datasets. But also I suggest to try my [text2vec](https://github.com/dselivanov/text2vec) package. Generally it is considerably memory friendly and doesn't require to load all the raw text into the RAM (for example it can create DTM for wikipedia dump on a 16gb laptop).

Second point is that I strongly don't recommend to convert data into `data.frame`. Try to work with `sparseMatrix` objects directly.

Following method will work good for text classification:

1. logistic regression with L1 penalty (see `glmnet` package)
2. Linear SVM (see `LiblineaR`, but worth to serach for alternatives)
3. Also worth to try `xgboost. I would prefer linear models. So you can try linear booster.

Comment: (took to much to edit that answer...)

I have been taking a look at the text2vec package and sounds interesting to me. I am considering to give it a try but I would need to understand how can I then use the DTM created to perform via classification - I need to be using caret -, as this object as I understand is a dgCMatrix or dgTMatrix. 

Could I be able to directly feed this object to the train function in caret?
Thanks!

Comment: `dgCMatrix` from `Matrix` package is the "standart" for sparse matrices in R. I didn't try `caret`, but you can be interested in this topic: https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/31 . Seems caret supports sparse matrices out of the box.

Comment: In fact `quanteda`s `dfm-class` inherits from `dgCMatrix-class`. So if your code works with `dfm-class`, in most cases it will work with `dgCMatrix` as well.

Comment: Thanks! Im working on it right now. Crossing fingers!

Comment: I get an error with caret and I'm not able to understand why it is complaining as I find little info around.

The error is:
Error in { : task 2 failed - "'n' must be a positive integer >= 'x'"

And it happens when I launch the train function. I guess I should open a new question to ask and put some source code for this?

Comment: I think so. But plz provide simple reproducible example with full pipeline.

Comment: I am afraid that it was a problem of tremendous disbalance in the dataset, so for now I will close the question.

Thanks a lot Dmitriy!

Comment: also plz, use dev version of text2vec from github. I recommend 0.4 from this branch https://github.com/dselivanov/text2vec/tree/0.4